# Getting Segmentation Fault error with strtok and fopen

Tags: c

Can anybody pls tell me why am I getting segmentation fault (core dumped) for this piece of code?

```
//Reading from the card.txt file
char *cards[54];
char *child_cards[54];
for(i=0; i<54; i++){
    cards[i] = malloc(100);
    child_cards[i] = malloc(100);
}

char buff[BUFSIZE];
char *p = NULL;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(argv[3], "r"); 

while(fgets(buff, 999, fp) != NULL) 
{
    p = strtok (buff," ");
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(cards[total_card], p);
        p = strtok (NULL, " ");           
        total_card += 1;
    }
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: [Please do not post images of code because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Code should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: Also don't forget to post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of incomplete code snippet that is not suit for feeding to compilers.

Comment: Where is the segfault?  Is `argv[3]` valid?  Is `total_card` initialized?  Too much information is missing here.

Comment: A complete example is one where the code posted doesn't need to be modified before it can be compiled and executed. If you want people to help you, then you have to make it easy for them to help you.

Comment: What is `BUFSIZE`? Can `buff` hold enough input from `fgets(buff, 999, fp)`? What is `total_card` What type is it? Where do you initialize it? Without a complete MRE we can only do wild guesses.

Comment: What arguments do you pass to your program? Does the file exist? You should check return value of `fopen`. What does the file contain?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few memory leaks.

For one, what is the BUFSIZE? I ask because you are using `fgets(buff, 999, fp)` which means the buffer size of that loop would be 999, possibly going over the BUFSIZE.

For two, it's best practice to specify a type when using `malloc()`

Goes as follows:

```
malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
```

Since malloc works in bytes, you would need the size of each character, times the amount of characters you want to use

Comment: There are many people who would dispute your "it's best practice" comment — see [Should I cast the result of `malloc()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/15168)  I happened to learn C on a system where the cast was imperative (in the days before standard C), so I don't look askance at the cast.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I hope my new edit is to your liking